# Perf report customize

Tags: perf

I used

```
perf record -a -g sleep 5
```

to profile, then I used

```
perf report  --stdio --no-children
```

to see the output, however it always shows like that:

```
# Overhead  Command         Shared Object      Symbol
    ........  ..............  .................  

    83.96%  swapper         [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] __intel_pmu_enable_all.isra.9
                   |
                   ---__intel_pmu_enable_all.isra.9
                      perf_event_task_tick
                      scheduler_tick
                      update_process_times
```

I just want to display only 3 columns as below for ex:

```
# Overhead        Period  Symbol
    ........  ............  
    1.94%     307054754  [.] ep_send_events_proc
    1.73%     274062724  [.] __audit_syscall_entry
    1.68%     265746126  [k] __switch_to
```

For Period column, I can add show-total-period to perf report, but how to exclude column Command and Shared Object in perf report?

Answer (score 1):

It should be simple to do this. Please read the `man page` for `perf report` if you want further modifications to your output.

Using the below command, you can exclude the columns `Command` and `Shared Object` from the `perf report` output.

`perf report -F overhead,period,symbol`

`-F` means include the subsequent fields in the `perf report` output. This will include the fields overhead, period and symbol just like the way you want it.